# Filter C# collection of float given a minimum difference value between adjacent elements

Tags: c#, collections, filtering, predicate

Suppose I have an ordered list of float (ascending).

I want to remove from it each element whose difference between next element and itself is less than a given threshold.

I need something like this:

```
List<float> orderedList;

IEnumerable<float> query = orderedList.Where(currentNum , nextNum => nextNum - currentNum < threshold);
```

Is that possible? If yes how?

Comment: Assuming a threshold of 2, what is the expected output of {1,2,3,4,10,20}? Per your rules, the output would be {4,10,20}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
List<float> orderedList = new List<float>() { 12, 14, 34, 45 };
List<float> itemsToRemove = orderedList.Where((item, index) =>
                            index < orderedList.Count - 1 &&
                            orderedList[index + 1] - item < threshhold).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
var filteredElements = new List<float>();
float ? prev = null;
orderedList.ToList().ForEach((e)=>{ 
              if (prev.HasValue)
              {
                  if (e-prev >= threshold)
                       filteredElements.Add(prev.Value);
              } 
              prev = e
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
var ls1 = ls.Where((item, index) => 
                   item - ls[ls.Count == index + 1 ? index : index + 1] >= 0);
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: What happens on the last element?

Comment: @AustinSalonen, good point raised, updated the answer as advised

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work.  (Though there are some potentially misunderstood implications of your question.)

```
var input = new List<float>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 29, 35, 40, 46, 59 };
var output = input.Zip(input.Skip(1).Concat(new[]{float.MaxValue}), (a, b) => new { a, b }).Where(x => x.b - x.a > 2).Select(x => x.a);
```

This produces the output of:

```
15, 18, 21, 24, 29, 35, 40, 46, 59
```

This has the advantage of working with any `IEnumerable`.

Comment: +1: thanks for the nice example. I realize my question was a bit vague, but I simplified the operation I was actually trying to do. What I really needed was the index of the current element on which the predicate was applied to. Anyway your example is really useful and interesting, thanks a lot.